# Capistrano Deleting Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

Every time I do a cap:deploy Capistrano is removing my assets saying that they are unneeded.  In fact they are needed and in order to get them back I have to do a cap:assets:precompile after every time I do a cap:deploy, otherwise my site has no styling or images.

Is this something with :normalize_asset_timestamps not working during deploy:finalize_update?

Capistrano v2.14.1, Rails v3.2.11

```
** Removing assets that haven't been deployed for 10080 minutes...
* executing ...
** [out :: server.com] comm:
** [out :: server.com] file 2 is not in sorted order
** [out :: server.com] Removing unneeded asset: application-66c9f07224da686e6b5a64752995df38.css
** [out :: server.com] Removing unneeded asset: application-66c9f07224da686e6b5a64752995df38.css.gz
** [out :: server.com] Removing unneeded asset: application-7b53d1e1411ed0a62ea32ace5ee4e7c2.js
** [out :: server.com] Removing unneeded asset: application-7b53d1e1411ed0a62ea32ace5ee4e7c2.js.gz
** [out :: server.com] Removing unneeded asset: application.css
** [out :: server.com] Removing unneeded asset: application.css.gz
** [out :: server.com] Removing unneeded asset: application.js
** [out :: server.com] Removing unneeded asset: application.js.gz
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/422

Either add

```
after "deploy", "assets:precompile"
```

at the end of your deploy.rb, and wait for capistrano gem to update

or add that 2 lines into your capistrano gem

or you could update capistrano direct from github

```
gem 'capistrano', git: 'https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano.git'
```

which i wouldn't reccomend

Comment: Thanks Stef! Now updating the capistrano gem works. The pullrequest you linked has been merged.

Comment: Thanx worked from me. I have used `after "deploy", "assets:precompile"`